# MySQL non-error error over web interfaces but not on command line

Tags: mysql

UPDATE queries work fine from the mysql command line, for any user.

However, when any UPDATE queries are run via a web interface (whether phpmyadmin or wordpress), the queries don't work, and I get a "no change" notice from mysql. *Most of the time.* The query is successful 10% of the time. Thing is there was a change, it just didn't take. I'm using the same user on phpmyadmin as on wordpress as on the command line client. I'm stumped. Anyone been here before?

Server details:

- Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
- MySQL client version: 5.1.61
- PHP extension: mysqli
- PHP version PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14

Update:
The "no change" notice comes from phpmyadmin. I don't get a "0 row(s) affected" from pma. When I return to the record that I attempted to edit, the edits aren't in there.

In wordpress, if it were a successful edit on a post I would get a "draft updated" or similar message. However, most of the time it just kicks me out to the wordpress admin index of posts without any message, and without any changes saved.

Comment: Who exactly gave you what message exactly? If you're getting `0 row(s) affected`, then the data was already in the table. Maybe stuff is getting run twice?

Comment: I included the reply I had written here in the original question above.

Comment: Mysterious. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Hi Daan, it's PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14 (included in original question).

Comment: Any leads in the php error log?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for taking the time to read here -- there aren't any leads in the php error log.

Comment: Related:  http://serverfault.com/questions/112565/mysql-works-with-straight-php-but-not-in-phpmyadmin-or-in-drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How this was fixed:

1. Clarified the apache server configuration. It was round-robining between two virtual hosts  due to non-specific domain conf files.
2. The timeout value in httpd.conf was set to 0. This created issues.